# leftJoin with same table return more records than expected (Query Builder)

Tags: mysql, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have created a query to fetch data to return to a view.

Query should return 8 records but instead returns 10 records. One order is wrongly replicated 3 time.

I could find out that the 2 following leftJoin with the same table are causing this error :

**LefJoin :**

```
->leftJoin('users_r3_details AS users_1', 'orders_detail_new.userID', '=', 'users_1.userID')
->leftJoin('users_r3_details AS users_2', 'orders_detail_new.customerID', '=', 'users_2.userID')
```

**Columns :**

```
'users_1.firstname AS FirstnameUser',
'users_1.lastname AS LastnameUser',
'users_2.firstname AS FirstnameCustomer',
'users_2.lastname AS LastnameCustomer',
```

I'm unable to fix it, so I would appreciate your expertise here.

Thanks

**Query :**

```
# SQL : GET THE ORDER DATA

$orders                     = DB::table('orders_detail_new')
                                ->leftJoin('status_order','orders_detail_new.statusorderID', '=', 'status_order.id')
                                ->leftJoin('users_r3_details AS users_1', 'orders_detail_new.userID', '=', 'users_1.userID')
                                ->leftJoin('users_r3_details AS users_2', 'orders_detail_new.customerID', '=', 'users_2.userID')
                                ->leftJoin('dessert_servings','orders_detail_new.dessertservingID', '=', 'dessert_servings.id')
                                ->leftJoin('product_types','orders_detail_new.producttype_ID', '=', 'product_types.producttypeID')
                                ->leftJoin('product_names','orders_detail_new.productname_ID', '=', 'product_names.productname_ID')
                                ->leftJoin('party_loaf_portions','orders_detail_new.ID_portion', '=', 'party_loaf_portions.portion_ID')
                                ->leftJoin('party_loaf_weights','orders_detail_new.partyloafweightID', '=', 'party_loaf_weights.id')
                                ->leftJoin('party_loaf_sandwiches_1','orders_detail_new.partyloafsandwich1ID', '=', 'party_loaf_sandwiches_1.id')
                                ->leftJoin('party_loaf_sandwiches_2','orders_detail_new.partyloafsandwich2ID', '=', 'party_loaf_sandwiches_2.id')
                                ->leftJoin('party_loaf_sandwiches_3','orders_detail_new.partyloafsandwich3ID', '=', 'party_loaf_sandwiches_3.id')
                                ->leftJoin('party_loaf_sandwiches_4','orders_detail_new.partyloafsandwich4ID', '=', 'party_loaf_sandwiches_4.id')
                                ->leftJoin('party_loaf_ribbons','orders_detail_new.partyloafribbonID', '=', 'party_loaf_ribbons.id')
                                ->leftJoin('savoury_canapes','orders_detail_new.canapeID', '=', 'savoury_canapes.id')
                                ->leftJoin('savoury_mini_puffs','orders_detail_new.minipuffID', '=', 'savoury_mini_puffs.id')
                                ->leftJoin('savoury_mini_vols_au_vent','orders_detail_new.minivolsauventID', '=', 'savoury_mini_vols_au_vent.id')
                                ->leftJoin('savoury_little_appetisers','orders_detail_new.littleappetiserID', '=', 'savoury_little_appetisers.id')
                                ->leftJoin('sweet_sweets','orders_detail_new.sweetID', '=', 'sweet_sweets.id')
                                ->select(
                                        'orders_detail_new.userID AS userID',
                                        'orders_detail_new.customerID AS customerID',
                                        'orders_detail_new.id AS rowID',
                                        'orders_detail_new.orderID AS orderID',
                                        'users_1.firstname AS FirstnameUser',
                                        'users_1.lastname AS LastnameUser',
                                        'users_2.firstname AS FirstnameCustomer',
                                        'users_2.lastname AS LastnameCustomer',
                                        'orders_detail_new.laboratory AS Laboratory',
                                        'orders_detail_new.ownerID AS ownerID',
                                        'orders_detail_new.statusorderID AS StatusID',
                                        'status_order.status_order AS Status',
                                        'orders_detail_new.deliverydate AS DeliveryDate',
                                        'product_types.product_type AS Type',
                                        'product_names.product_name AS Name',
                                        'dessert_servings.serving_persons AS Servings',
                                        'orders_detail_new.desserttextmessage AS Message',
                                        'orders_detail_new.dessertdecorchocolateID AS DecoChocoFruits',
                                        'orders_detail_new.dessertdecorflowerID AS DecoSmallFlowers',
                                        'orders_detail_new.piedecoration AS Decoration',
                                        'party_loaf_portions.portions AS Portions',
                                        'party_loaf_weights.weight AS Weight',
                                        'party_loaf_sandwiches_1.assortment AS Assortment1',
                                        'party_loaf_sandwiches_2.assortment AS Assortment2',
                                        'party_loaf_sandwiches_3.assortment AS Assortment3',
                                        'party_loaf_sandwiches_4.assortment AS Assortment4',
                                        'party_loaf_ribbons.color AS RibbonColor',
                                        'slicescutID AS Cut',
                                        'bread_quantity AS BreadQuantity',
                                        'savoury_canapes.assortment AS CanapésAssortment',
                                        'savoury_mini_puffs.assortment AS MiniPuffsAssortment',
                                        'savoury_mini_vols_au_vent.assortment AS VolsAuVentAssortment',
                                        'savoury_little_appetisers.assortment AS AppetisersAssortment',
                                        'sweet_sweets.assortment AS SweetAssortment',
                                        'orders_detail_new.sweet_quantity AS SweetQuantity',
                                        'orders_detail_new.savoury_quantity AS SavouryQuantity',
                                        'orders_detail_new.productprice AS Price',
                                        'orders_detail_new.productaddfee AS Surcharge',
                                        'orders_detail_new.piedecorationprice AS DecoSurcharge',
                                        'orders_detail_new.subtotal AS Total'
                                        )
                                ### ->orderby('orders_detail_new.id', '=', 'asc')
                                ->where('orders_detail_new.producttype_ID', '=', 4) // FOR test PURPOSE
                                ->where('orders_detail_new.productname', '=', 26) // FOR test PURPOSE
                                ### ->take(5) // FOR test PURPOSE
                                ->get();

dd($orders);
```

dd(orders)

```
Collection {#2265 ▼
  #items: array:10 [▼
    0 => {#2257 ▼
      +"userID": 22
      +"customerID": 31
      +"rowID": 1019
      +"orderID": 1007
      +"FirstnameUser": "Un"
      +"LastnameUser": "Admin"
      +"FirstnameCustomer": "Daniel"
      +"LastnameCustomer": "Favre"
      +"Laboratory": "Boulanger [Claude];Cuisine"
      +"ownerID": null
      +"StatusID": 2
      +"Status": "Non traitée"
      +"DeliveryDate": "2019-09-02"
      +"Type": "Pain-surprise"
      +"Name": "Mélangé"
      +"Servings": null
      +"Message": null
      +"DecoChocoFruits": "Pas de décoration chocolat et fruits"
      +"DecoSmallFlowers": "Pas de décoration petites fleurs"
      +"Decoration": null
      +"Portions": "100"
      +"Weight": "2.5 Kg"
      +"Assortment1": "Confiture Fraise"
      +"Assortment2": "Foie gras"
      +"Assortment3": "Gruyère"
      +"Assortment4": "Jambon"
      +"RibbonColor": "Blanc"
      +"Cut": "Pas de coupe"
      +"BreadQuantity": null
      +"CanapésAssortment": null
      +"MiniPuffsAssortment": null
      +"VolsAuVentAssortment": null
      +"AppetisersAssortment": null
      +"SweetAssortment": null
      +"SweetQuantity": null
      +"SavouryQuantity": null
      +"Price": "89.00"
      +"Surcharge": "0.00"
      +"DecoSurcharge": "0.00"
      +"Total": "89.00"
    }
    1 => {#2258 ▼
      +"userID": 22
      +"customerID": 31
      +"rowID": 1019
      +"orderID": 1007
      +"FirstnameUser": "Un"
      +"LastnameUser": "Admin"
      +"FirstnameCustomer": "Daniel"
      +"LastnameCustomer": "Favre"
      +"Laboratory": "Boulanger [Claude];Cuisine"
      +"ownerID": null
      +"StatusID": 2
      +"Status": "Non traitée"
      +"DeliveryDate": "2019-09-02"
      +"Type": "Pain-surprise"
      +"Name": "Mélangé"
      +"Servings": null
      +"Message": null
      +"DecoChocoFruits": "Pas de décoration chocolat et fruits"
      +"DecoSmallFlowers": "Pas de décoration petites fleurs"
      +"Decoration": null
      +"Portions": "100"
      +"Weight": "2.5 Kg"
      +"Assortment1": "Confiture Fraise"
      +"Assortment2": "Foie gras"
      +"Assortment3": "Gruyère"
      +"Assortment4": "Jambon"
      +"RibbonColor": "Blanc"
      +"Cut": "Pas de coupe"
      +"BreadQuantity": null
      +"CanapésAssortment": null
      +"MiniPuffsAssortment": null
      +"VolsAuVentAssortment": null
      +"AppetisersAssortment": null
      +"SweetAssortment": null
      +"SweetQuantity": null
      +"SavouryQuantity": null
      +"Price": "89.00"
      +"Surcharge": "0.00"
      +"DecoSurcharge": "0.00"
      +"Total": "89.00"
    }
    2 => {#2264 ▼
      +"userID": 22
      +"customerID": 31
      +"rowID": 1019
      +"orderID": 1007
      +"FirstnameUser": "Un"
      +"LastnameUser": "Admin"
      +"FirstnameCustomer": "Daniel"
      +"LastnameCustomer": "Favre"
      +"Laboratory": "Boulanger [Claude];Cuisine"
      +"ownerID": null
      +"StatusID": 2
      +"Status": "Non traitée"
      +"DeliveryDate": "2019-09-02"
      +"Type": "Pain-surprise"
      +"Name": "Mélangé"
      +"Servings": null
      +"Message": null
      +"DecoChocoFruits": "Pas de décoration chocolat et fruits"
      +"DecoSmallFlowers": "Pas de décoration petites fleurs"
      +"Decoration": null
      +"Portions": "100"
      +"Weight": "2.5 Kg"
      +"Assortment1": "Confiture Fraise"
      +"Assortment2": "Foie gras"
      +"Assortment3": "Gruyère"
      +"Assortment4": "Jambon"
      +"RibbonColor": "Blanc"
      +"Cut": "Pas de coupe"
      +"BreadQuantity": null
      +"CanapésAssortment": null
      +"MiniPuffsAssortment": null
      +"VolsAuVentAssortment": null
      +"AppetisersAssortment": null
      +"SweetAssortment": null
      +"SweetQuantity": null
      +"SavouryQuantity": null
      +"Price": "89.00"
      +"Surcharge": "0.00"
      +"DecoSurcharge": "0.00"
      +"Total": "89.00"
    }
    3 => {#2259 ▼
      +"userID": 9
      +"customerID": null
      +"rowID": 1029
      +"orderID": 1008
      +"FirstnameUser": "Client"
      +"LastnameUser": "Test"
      +"FirstnameCustomer": null
      +"LastnameCustomer": null
      +"Laboratory": "Boulanger [Claude];Cuisine"
      +"ownerID": null
      +"StatusID": 2
      +"Status": "Non traitée"
      +"DeliveryDate": "2019-06-30"
      +"Type": "Pain-surprise"
      +"Name": "Mélangé"
      +"Servings": null
      +"Message": null
      +"DecoChocoFruits": "Pas de décoration chocolat et fruits"
      +"DecoSmallFlowers": "Pas de décoration petites fleurs"
      +"Decoration": null
      +"Portions": "100"
      +"Weight": "2.5 Kg"
      +"Assortment1": "Confiture Fraise"
      +"Assortment2": "Foie gras"
      +"Assortment3": "Gruyère"
      +"Assortment4": "Jambon"
      +"RibbonColor": "Blanc"
      +"Cut": "Pas de coupe"
      +"BreadQuantity": null
      +"CanapésAssortment": null
      +"MiniPuffsAssortment": null
      +"VolsAuVentAssortment": null
      +"AppetisersAssortment": null
      +"SweetAssortment": null
      +"SweetQuantity": null
      +"SavouryQuantity": null
      +"Price": "89.00"
      +"Surcharge": "0.00"
      +"DecoSurcharge": "0.00"
      +"Total": "89.00"
    }
    4 => {#2262 ▼
      +"userID": 9
      +"customerID": null
      +"rowID": 1039
      +"orderID": 1009
      +"FirstnameUser": "Client"
      +"LastnameUser": "Test"
      +"FirstnameCustomer": null
      +"LastnameCustomer": null
      +"Laboratory": "Boulanger [Claude];Cuisine"
      +"ownerID": null
      +"StatusID": 2
      +"Status": "Non traitée"
      +"DeliveryDate": "2019-06-30"
      +"Type": "Pain-surprise"
      +"Name": "Mélangé"
      +"Servings": null
      +"Message": null
      +"DecoChocoFruits": "Pas de décoration chocolat et fruits"
      +"DecoSmallFlowers": "Pas de décoration petites fleurs"
      +"Decoration": null
      +"Portions": "100"
      +"Weight": "2.5 Kg"
      +"Assortment1": "Confiture Fraise"
      +"Assortment2": "Foie gras"
      +"Assortment3": "Gruyère"
      +"Assortment4": "Jambon"
      +"RibbonColor": "Blanc"
      +"Cut": "Pas de coupe"
      +"BreadQuantity": null
      +"CanapésAssortment": null
      +"MiniPuffsAssortment": null
      +"VolsAuVentAssortment": null
      +"AppetisersAssortment": null
      +"SweetAssortment": null
      +"SweetQuantity": null
      +"SavouryQuantity": null
      +"Price": "89.00"
      +"Surcharge": "0.00"
      +"DecoSurcharge": "0.00"
      +"Total": "89.00"
    }
    5 => {#2260 ▼
      +"userID": 9
      +"customerID": null
      +"rowID": 1049
      +"orderID": 1010
      +"FirstnameUser": "Client"
      +"LastnameUser": "Test"
      +"FirstnameCustomer": null
      +"LastnameCustomer": null
      +"Laboratory": "Boulanger [Claude];Cuisine"
      +"ownerID": null
      +"StatusID": 2
      +"Status": "Non traitée"
      +"DeliveryDate": "2019-06-30"
      +"Type": "Pain-surprise"
      +"Name": "Mélangé"
      +"Servings": null
      +"Message": null
      +"DecoChocoFruits": "Pas de décoration chocolat et fruits"
      +"DecoSmallFlowers": "Pas de décoration petites fleurs"
      +"Decoration": null
      +"Portions": "100"
      +"Weight": "2.5 Kg"
      +"Assortment1": "Confiture Fraise"
      +"Assortment2": "Foie gras"
      +"Assortment3": "Gruyère"
      +"Assortment4": "Jambon"
      +"RibbonColor": "Blanc"
      +"Cut": "Pas de coupe"
      +"BreadQuantity": null
      +"CanapésAssortment": null
      +"MiniPuffsAssortment": null
      +"VolsAuVentAssortment": null
      +"AppetisersAssortment": null
      +"SweetAssortment": null
      +"SweetQuantity": null
      +"SavouryQuantity": null
      +"Price": "89.00"
      +"Surcharge": "0.00"
      +"DecoSurcharge": "0.00"
      +"Total": "89.00"
    }
    6 => {#2261 ▼
      +"userID": 9
      +"customerID": null
      +"rowID": 1059
      +"orderID": 1011
      +"FirstnameUser": "Client"
      +"LastnameUser": "Test"
      +"FirstnameCustomer": null
      +"LastnameCustomer": null
      +"Laboratory": "Boulanger [Claude];Cuisine"
      +"ownerID": null
      +"StatusID": 2
      +"Status": "Non traitée"
      +"DeliveryDate": "2019-06-30"
      +"Type": "Pain-surprise"
      +"Name": "Mélangé"
      +"Servings": null
      +"Message": null
      +"DecoChocoFruits": "Pas de décoration chocolat et fruits"
      +"DecoSmallFlowers": "Pas de décoration petites fleurs"
      +"Decoration": null
      +"Portions": "100"
      +"Weight": "2.5 Kg"
      +"Assortment1": "Confiture Fraise"
      +"Assortment2": "Foie gras"
      +"Assortment3": "Gruyère"
      +"Assortment4": "Jambon"
      +"RibbonColor": "Blanc"
      +"Cut": "Pas de coupe"
      +"BreadQuantity": null
      +"CanapésAssortment": null
      +"MiniPuffsAssortment": null
      +"VolsAuVentAssortment": null
      +"AppetisersAssortment": null
      +"SweetAssortment": null
      +"SweetQuantity": null
      +"SavouryQuantity": null
      +"Price": "89.00"
      +"Surcharge": "0.00"
      +"DecoSurcharge": "0.00"
      +"Total": "89.00"
    }
    7 => {#2266 ▼
      +"userID": 9
      +"customerID": null
      +"rowID": 1069
      +"orderID": 1012
      +"FirstnameUser": "Client"
      +"LastnameUser": "Test"
      +"FirstnameCustomer": null
      +"LastnameCustomer": null
      +"Laboratory": "Boulanger [Claude];Cuisine"
      +"ownerID": null
      +"StatusID": 2
      +"Status": "Non traitée"
      +"DeliveryDate": "2019-06-30"
      +"Type": "Pain-surprise"
      +"Name": "Mélangé"
      +"Servings": null
      +"Message": null
      +"DecoChocoFruits": "Pas de décoration chocolat et fruits"
      +"DecoSmallFlowers": "Pas de décoration petites fleurs"
      +"Decoration": null
      +"Portions": "100"
      +"Weight": "2.5 Kg"
      +"Assortment1": "Confiture Fraise"
      +"Assortment2": "Foie gras"
      +"Assortment3": "Gruyère"
      +"Assortment4": "Jambon"
      +"RibbonColor": "Blanc"
      +"Cut": "Pas de coupe"
      +"BreadQuantity": null
      +"CanapésAssortment": null
      +"MiniPuffsAssortment": null
      +"VolsAuVentAssortment": null
      +"AppetisersAssortment": null
      +"SweetAssortment": null
      +"SweetQuantity": null
      +"SavouryQuantity": null
      +"Price": "89.00"
      +"Surcharge": "0.00"
      +"DecoSurcharge": "0.00"
      +"Total": "89.00"
    }
    8 => {#2267 ▼
      +"userID": 9
      +"customerID": null
      +"rowID": 1079
      +"orderID": 1013
      +"FirstnameUser": "Client"
      +"LastnameUser": "Test"
      +"FirstnameCustomer": null
      +"LastnameCustomer": null
      +"Laboratory": "Boulanger [Claude];Cuisine"
      +"ownerID": null
      +"StatusID": 2
      +"Status": "Non traitée"
      +"DeliveryDate": "2019-06-30"
      +"Type": "Pain-surprise"
      +"Name": "Mélangé"
      +"Servings": null
      +"Message": null
      +"DecoChocoFruits": "Pas de décoration chocolat et fruits"
      +"DecoSmallFlowers": "Pas de décoration petites fleurs"
      +"Decoration": null
      +"Portions": "100"
      +"Weight": "2.5 Kg"
      +"Assortment1": "Confiture Fraise"
      +"Assortment2": "Foie gras"
      +"Assortment3": "Gruyère"
      +"Assortment4": "Jambon"
      +"RibbonColor": "Blanc"
      +"Cut": "Pas de coupe"
      +"BreadQuantity": null
      +"CanapésAssortment": null
      +"MiniPuffsAssortment": null
      +"VolsAuVentAssortment": null
      +"AppetisersAssortment": null
      +"SweetAssortment": null
      +"SweetQuantity": null
      +"SavouryQuantity": null
      +"Price": "89.00"
      +"Surcharge": "0.00"
      +"DecoSurcharge": "0.00"
      +"Total": "89.00"
    }
    9 => {#2268 ▼
      +"userID": 9
      +"customerID": null
      +"rowID": 1089
      +"orderID": 1014
      +"FirstnameUser": "Client"
      +"LastnameUser": "Test"
      +"FirstnameCustomer": null
      +"LastnameCustomer": null
      +"Laboratory": "Boulanger [Claude];Cuisine"
      +"ownerID": null
      +"StatusID": 2
      +"Status": "Non traitée"
      +"DeliveryDate": "2019-06-30"
      +"Type": "Pain-surprise"
      +"Name": "Mélangé"
      +"Servings": null
      +"Message": null
      +"DecoChocoFruits": "Pas de décoration chocolat et fruits"
      +"DecoSmallFlowers": "Pas de décoration petites fleurs"
      +"Decoration": null
      +"Portions": "100"
      +"Weight": "2.5 Kg"
      +"Assortment1": "Confiture Fraise"
      +"Assortment2": "Foie gras"
      +"Assortment3": "Gruyère"
      +"Assortment4": "Jambon"
      +"RibbonColor": "Blanc"
      +"Cut": "Pas de coupe"
      +"BreadQuantity": null
      +"CanapésAssortment": null
      +"MiniPuffsAssortment": null
      +"VolsAuVentAssortment": null
      +"AppetisersAssortment": null
      +"SweetAssortment": null
      +"SweetQuantity": null
      +"SavouryQuantity": null
      +"Price": "89.00"
      +"Surcharge": "0.00"
      +"DecoSurcharge": "0.00"
      +"Total": "89.00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting there are same users with same customerId. try adding these.

```
->where('orders_detail_new.customerID', '!=', 'users_1.userID') 
->where('orders_detail_new.userID', '!=', 'users_2.userID')
```

or

```
->where('orders_detail_new.customerID', '!=', 'users_1.userID')
```

or

```
->where('orders_detail_new.userID', '!=', 'users_2.userID')
```

last option

```
->leftJoin('sweet_sweets','orders_detail_new.sweetID', '=', 'sweet_sweets.id')
->distinct()
->select(
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but now instead of 8 records which should be returned (tested in MYSQL without all the left join SELECT count(`id`) FROM `orders_detail_new` WHERE `producttype_ID` = 4 and `productname_ID` = 26), only 3 are returned...

Comment: try remove the 2nd one.

Comment: same output, 3 records returned

Comment: it is a data issue, try remove the first one and retain the 2nd one

Comment: if you have screenshot of the result, it will help. So we will not focus only on this table

Comment: I just added the dd output so you can see that the 3 first records of the collection are the same order -> 1007, which is replicated 3 times

Comment: seems a data issue, our last option is to select distinct()

Comment: Of course distinct, totally forgot this one, working fine now, thank you @metal for your time, appreciated

Comment: good, it would be better if you will able to find out which table is giving duplicates. Please don't forget to accept this answer

Comment: Yes of course, I will try to find it when I have more time for it, thanks

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: well, that's not me.

Comment: Comment was meant for the guy issuing penalty points for a reason I don't understand even if I don't care about point, but care about principle. Thanks again for your help and solution to my issue, which is solved nicely

Comment: well, i also have negative votes on some of my questions here in SO, which i really don't have any idea.

Comment: I was just upset for a second, since I don't understand the meaning and expectation of doing this. This is a platform for helping, sharing knowledge not for sanctioning people. I'm not omniscient and perfect, and that's ok I guess, and sometimes I need some help for it might be trivial issues, that's happen. Thanks anyway @metal and take care.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION FROM @metal

Add distinct in the query :

```
...
->distinct()
->get();
```